# Make rectangle in Vis.js

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-visualization, visualization, vis.js

I'm using Vis.js and I'm trying to make a rectangle. According to the documentation, you can only create a square and so, I was trying to find a way to change the sizes of the square in order to create a rectangle.

How can I do this?
So far I've checked the documentation online for the nodes: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/nodes.html

And I've tried using the heightConstraint and the widthConstraint attributes:

```
nodes.add({id:transition, shape:'square', heightConstraint: {minimum:5, maximum:30}, widthConstraint: {minimum:5, maximum:30}, physics:'false', label:transition, size:10});
```

But this doesn't work since I'm still left with squares instead of rectangles.

Thank you all!

Comment: Hello. What have you tried so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: Edited the question to include the code I've tried using :)

Comment: How is this connected to Python?

Comment: I have a frontend with html/css where I'm creating the network and I'm communicating with a python backend through flask.